Изменить положение конечной точки вектора
Все здравствуйте.
У меня есть вектор(3d) с его начальной точкой с её координатами и есть его конечная точка, так же с координатами.
Вопрос такой - мне нужно сместить на определённое расстояние конечную точку вектора назад, в обратном направлении, по этому вектору.


это школьная алгебра.

Сначала терминология: вектор это три числа (в 3D). У него не может быть координат начальной и конечной точек, вектор - это только разница между двумя координатами. То что у вас - это скорее направленный отрезок.

Определяем направление: координаты конечной точки минус координаты начальной точки (покоординатно вычитаем, получаем вектор).
Нормализуем (то есть делим на его длину, то есть на sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z), чтобы сделать его длиной 1).
Вычитаем из конечной точки этот вектор, умноженный на желаемое расстояние.


Ок, спасибо. А если попробовать получить конечную точку из длинны вектора, это будет быстрее или нет? Т.е. уменьшить длинну вектора и соответственно получить конечную точку и если это возможно и быстрее то как?

@AnatolFaru если «определённое расстояние» это на самом деле не число, а например «уменьшить на 10%», то можно обойтись без вычисления квадратного корня.

@HolyBlackCat  vDir = end_pos - start_pos;//Направление вектора   lenght = (lenght).Length;//Длина вектора   VectorNormalize(vDir);//Нормализация  desired_pos = end_pos - (lenght - нужное расстояние);  Или такой вариант (desired_pos = end_pos - (lenght * нужное расстояние);)    Фрматирование здесь - тупее просто некуда.

Длина вектора это flooat, вектор и точка это Vector

@AnatolFaru "если попробовать получить конечную точку из длинны вектора, это будет быстрее или нет?" Сходу кажется, что не быстрее, но вы попробуйте. "Фрматирование здесь - тупее просто некуда" Чтобы форматировалось нормально, надо в обратные кавычки завернуть код. А это вы что скинули? В таком виде все заработало?

@HolyBlackCat
Заработать то конечно заработало, естественно с доработками непосредственно в самом коде, вектор напрямую на float конечно ошибку выдаст, здесь мне главное было понять принцип. Я не стал мучаться с получением конечной точки из длины вектора, у меня основной вопрос стоял с движением NPC и их AI, конечная точка, после трассировки, получалась очень близко к препятствиям, вот и появился такой вопрос. Сейчас все отлично работает. Спасибо еще раз за помощь.

Все достаточно просто и даже просто расписав на бумажке вы уже почти всё поймёте.

Переносите вектор в начало координат
Нормализуете вектор
Умножаете нормальный вектор на нужное расстояние
Полученный вектор вычитаете из конечной точки изначального вектора.


У вектора нет начальной точки, можно считать, что это нулевая координата.
Уменьшить длину вектора на заданную величину можно так:
Vnew = V - Delta * V / Len(V)


Что такое Delta в этой формуле?

Delta - смещение конечной точки на определённое расстояние, как у вас написано

Спасибо. Попробую еще и этот вариант. Ну и опять-же, а в чём выражается эта Delta? Это Vector, float(скаляр), и вообще как это значение получить? Вернее как получить или узнать это значение?

Вообще, что-то очень интересное, нужно обязательно поэкспериментировать с этим.

Все ответы означают одно и то же.
